# What are Native-sized integers in C# 9.0?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-9.0

- What are these native-sized integers; `nint` and `nuint`?
- What are they used for and what are the benefits of them ?

Comment: relevant docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nint-nuint

Comment: The first three lines of @Sommmen's link says it all: "Starting in C# 9.0, you can use the nint and nuint keywords to define native-sized integers. These are 32-bit integers when running in a 32-bit process, or 64-bit integers when running in a 64-bit process. They can be used for interop scenarios, low-level libraries, and to optimize performance in scenarios where integer math is used extensively."

Comment: Another [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/native-integers).

Answer (score 5):

These are integer types that will have a range and size compliant with the "word size" on the cpu architecture the software is running on.

If the software is running as a 32-bit process, they will be 32-bit in size and range, and if the software is running as a 64-bit process, they will be 64-bit in size and range.

Their predominant use is to be easier to write interop code that talks to other libraries that are written for those 32-bit/64-bit CPUs, in that you can actually use them as integers and don't have to use `IntPtr` which is an opaque integer of the same size.

So this is basically just a proper integer-type that you can use instead of `IntPtr` for these purposes.

You can check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nint-nuint) for more information. It also mentions this:

> ... and to optimize performance in scenarios where integer math is used extensively.

There might be (slight) performance penalties in dealing with 64-bit integers in a 32-bit process, or 32-bit integers in a 64-bit process (although probably less so for this variant), so using the right integer type in the right process type might be beneficial if you need to eke out the last ounce of performance.

Comment: @damien, in my experience, when I have to eke out the last ounce of performance, my reaction to the code I'm writing is usually "eek", but you're right of course :)